# Where to find Microsoft Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, legacy-database

I have an old MS Access 97 database that I need to open in 2020.
Apparently it is possible by following an official procedure described here:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd?ocmsassetID=HA102749625&ctt=1&CorrelationId=4c3fb7ac-f990-448e-a970-9b249c2f9b11&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

The question is, where do I get Access 2003 in 2020? :D

Comment: This is not a software development question.  Please read [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Maybe E-bay?? Did you do web search before coming here? https://download.cnet.com/Access-2003-Conversion-Toolkit/3000-2064_4-10744513.html

Comment: @June7 This tool you have linked is upgrading a 97 database to 2003. Hence it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't be a software development question, considering it is a genuine problem in software development, because I am not asking where to buy software, but specifically about a very old piece of software that I require for software development. @DaveS

Comment: And to everyone else who closed this post, obvioulsy I have seen that answer you linked, and it did not help me.

Comment: What version of Access are you running? Converting 97 to 2003 (mdb) is an intermediate step to get db in a version that can be opened by latest Access and allow conversion to accdb. If the conversion toolkit accomplishes that, Access 2003 is not really needed. Your link actually says 2007 or 2010 can convert a 97 file. I have Access 2010 and it can still be purchased. What else could you mean by 'get' than buying? There is no code in your question for analysis and therefore question is not really suited to SO.

Comment: "Where to find (program)" is a software buying question.  Please read [tour] and [ask].

Comment: "What application converts file format A to file format B" is probably better as a SuperUser.com question since you're talking about using an application not writing your own conversion code, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: [This](https://www.kean.edu/~ocisweb/downloadf/Office-Pro_2003/) this looks like it might work...